# Proof of lemma in order to prove Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality without defining a new function to do so. Specifically I am trying to show that:

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_k\right)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 \sum_{k=1}^nb_k^2 - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(a_kb_j-a_jb_k)^2$$

Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand the square:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} (a_k b_j - a_j b_k)^2=\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (a_k^2 b_j^2 - 2 a_k b_k a_j b_j + a_j^2 b_k^2)$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_k^2 b_j^2 - 2 \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_k b_k a_j b_j  + \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2 b_k^2$$

Using the distributive property we see this equals

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2\right) - 2 \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j b_j\right)+ \left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k\right).$$

The first and the third terms are equal, so we get

$$2\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2\right) - 2 \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j b_j\right).$$

Rearrange the terms.